# FastAPI isn't working when being accessed by IPv4. (On another device)

Tags: python, localhost, backend, hosting, fastapi

Initially, I was trying it out with react, I made a TCP port opening for port: 5000 on my windows defender firewall settings and when I ran react on 5000, I could access the frontend from any device on LAN (my phone, other laptop).

However, when I try running my FastAPI server on port 5000, I can only access it locally. I've tried using middleware, changing the hostname from `0.0.0.0` to `IPV4`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
from models import *

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.post('/post/')
async def create_post(item: HomeButton):
    print(item.number)
    return {"Post": "Success"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
    #uvicorn.run(app, host="25.21.135.32", port=5000)
```

Ngrok'ing it worked just fine, but my goal is to run FastAPI locally. I've also tried different ports, i've even tried using an express server instead and experiencing the same issues.

In the `netstat` command in CMD, the port is listed there, but not as "ESTABLISHED" Rather "TIME_WAIT"
[image: time wait..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, try going into `settings`->`Network status`->`Properties` and if the network profile is set on public, try changing it to private